# MySQL: Join multiple rows and count occurances in one query

Tags: mysql

I’m trying to realize a SQL query, which joins multiple rows and also returns the number of occurances for equal values.

```
ID    Row_1    Row_2    Row_3
1     Value    NULL     NULL
2     NULL     Value    Value
3     NULL     Value    NULL
4     NULL     Value2   NULL
```

The query should return two rows

```
ID    Row     Count
1*    Value   3
4     Value2  1
```

The ID for the first returned row doesn’t matter. If value is unique over all three original rows the original ID should be returned (as shown in row 2 of result set). I have to mention, that there are over 50.000 rows in the table. It should not taking too much time.

I tried several approaches like joining the table with itself. Nothing really solved the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Marco

Comment: So you want to know how many columns a certain value exists in (not how many times the value appears)? So, in this case, the count would always be between 0 and 3, inclusive? Or you want to know how many rows it's in?

Comment: In how many rows it’s in. And getting unique values in the joined row also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can create a subquery that assembles a list of all non-null values, then JOIN to that.

Subquery for list of values:

```
SELECT row_1 AS val FROM mytable WHERE row_1 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT row_2 AS val FROM mytable WHERE row_2 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT row_3 AS val FROM mytable WHERE row_3 IS NOT NULL
```

*(`UNION` implicitly performs a `DISTINCT`, so the resulting list will not have duplicate values.)*

Then we can JOIN that to get our counts:

```
SELECT m.id, v.val AS `row`, COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM mytable m
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT row_1 AS val FROM mytable WHERE row_1 IS NOT NULL
  UNION
  SELECT row_2 AS val FROM mytable WHERE row_2 IS NOT NULL
  UNION
  SELECT row_3 AS val FROM mytable WHERE row_3 IS NOT NULL
) v
  ON v.val = m.row_1
    OR v.val = m.row_2
    OR v.val = m.row_3
GROUP BY v.val
```

Here's a [working example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86328/3).

Comment: This looks very promising. I will give it a try with my whole table. Probably this will take some time. But it works at least as I could see on SQL Fiddle. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can do like ::

```
Select 
ID, 
CONCAT(ifnull(ROW_1,''), ifnull(ROW_2,''), ifnull(ROW_3,'')) as `temp_ROW`,
count(1) as count

from table group by temp_ROW;
```

Comment: `count(1) as count`? is this a reference to the row?

Comment: Occurance of value in Row_1 and Row_2 for the same row is also possible. So that this CONCAT solutation doesn’t work. Thanks anyway.